# How to select multiple fields from different sources in sql?

Tags: sql

I have these three tables here

- Aircraft (aid, aname, cruisingrange)
- Employee (eid, ename, salary)
- Certified (eid, aid)

For aircraft with cruisingrange over 1000 miles, `SELECT` the aircraft name and the average salary of all pilots who have flown these aircrafts.

Note that pilot and employee are the same.

I spent a lot time thinking about this problem but I couldn't write a SQL query. Please help me

Comment: please provide schema and sample data as well as expect output. those will greatly help us clarify the problem. BTW about this problem here is some hint `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the query that shows avg salary of pilots who flown aircraft with over 1000 miles:

```
   select 
        aname
        , AVG(salary) AvgSalary
    from 
    AirCraft
    join Certified 
        on AirCraft.aid = Certified.aid
        and Aircraft.cruisingrange > 1000
    join Employee
        on Employee.eid = Certified.eid 
    group by
        aname
```